# How to call XML Schema Content in HTML via PHP

Tags: php, html, css, xml

I am trying to pull data from an XML file which has colon in the tags may be schema based and needs to show the data in a HTML webpage using PHP,

Here I am not able to get the data pulled from XML into the HTML page.

This is the Actual XML Document need to pull data from,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tns:DisplayRequest xmlns:tns="http://gide.com/display/" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://gide.com/display/ display_schema.xsd ">
  <tns:DisplayRequestData>
    <tns:DisplayData displayPort="D-001">
      <tns:laneIndex>01</tns:laneIndex>
      <tns:plateNumber>PLATE-01</tns:plateNumber>
      <tns:bayIndex>B001</tns:bayIndex>
    </tns:DisplayData>
  </tns:DisplayRequestData>
</tns:DisplayRequest>
```

I have tried the same without colons, in the XML and the HTML code, it runs well and data is pulled and shown in the HTML page,

I tried using this HTML CODE,

```
<table border="2px">
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2">Truck Loading Station</th>
  </tr>

    <tr>
        <th>Bay</td>
        <th>Truck Number</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <? $xml=simplexml_load_file("test.xml");?>
        <td><?php echo $xml->tnsbayIndex; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $xml->tnsplateNumber; ?></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

XML Code I modified (removed colons),

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tns:DisplayRequest xmlns:tns="http://gide.com/display/" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://gide.com/display/display_schema.xsd">
  <!-- <tnsDisplayRequestData> -->
    <!-- <tnsDisplayData> -->
  <tnslaneIndex>04</tnslaneIndex>
  <tnsplateNumber>PLATE-04</tnsplateNumber>
  <tnsbayIndex>B004</tnsbayIndex>
<!-- </tnsDisplayData> 
</tnsDisplayRequestData> -->
</tns:DisplayRequest>
```

But when I add the "colons" back, I don't get any output.

Please can some one help me in this?

**P.S. I am not allowed to do any change in XML file and need to pull data from it**

I would really be glad for the HELP.

Expected Result is that the XML data is pulled and displayed in the HTML page

Answer (score 0):

Try using

Html headers are normally required and some str_replace for encoding but the above should help

Also php simplexml_load_string can be used along with a $foo = print_r($array, true); 
Allowing you to iterate anywhere you see fit.

Comment: can you explain with taking some example from above?

Answer (score 0):

```js
<?php
$myXMLData =
"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<note>
<to>Tove</to>
<from>Jani</from>
<heading>Reminder</heading>
<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>";
enter code here
$xml=simplexml_load_string($myXMLData) or die("Error: Cannot create object");
print_r($xml);
?>
```

Comment: this isn't helping brother.